# show div only user selects specific radio button - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I'm new to Angular 5 and I'm having radio button like component in my app as follows.

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="vehicles">
      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-secondary active">
             <input ngbButton type="radio" name="mode" [value]="true" > Toyota
      </label>

      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input ngbButton type="radio" name="mode" [value]="false"> Nissan
      </label>
 </div>
```

I also have a separate div as follows. I want to show that `div` only a user selects Nissan button. I try to use `ngif`. But failed. Can someone please help me.

```
           <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Vehicle Type</label>
                                <ng-select

                                        [items]="vehicleTypes"
                                        bindLabel="name"
                                        bindValue="id"
                                        [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicleTypesId"
                                        >
                                </ng-select>
                            </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan . could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try.

```
   <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input  type="radio"  [(ngModel)]="show" name="bn" [value]="true"> Show
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input  type="radio" [(ngModel)]="show" name="bn" [value]='false'> ShowSecond </label>

    <div *ngIf="show">
        This will be togled for 1st Radio
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!show">
        This will be togled for 2nd Radio
    </div>
```

Declare a property `show` in you component as `boolean` and initialize it to `false`.

```
 show: boolean = false;
```

Here is a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tk1bv3) of the same.
You can now change things according to your own code and structure.

Hope this helps